# Does SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor use only one thread without concurrency in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, concurrency, threadpool

I'm learning about ThreadPoolTaskExecutor in Spring Boot Microservice. And I have a couple of microservice like accounts, cards, loans with h2 database. And I did some tests, one test is creating the bean ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.

So I have only this code:

```
    @PostMapping("/myCustomerDetails")
    public ResponseEntity<CustomerDetails> myCustomerDetails(
            @RequestBody Customer customer) {

        CustomerDetails customerDetails;

        try {
            long startRequestTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            logger.info("Started thread requests");

            CompletableFuture<Accounts> accountDetails =
                    retrieveDetailsAsync.getAccountsDetails(customer.getCustomerId());

            CompletableFuture<List<Loans>> loansDetails =
                    retrieveDetailsAsync.getLoansDetails(correlationId, customer);

            CompletableFuture<List<Cards>> cardsDetails =
                    retrieveDetailsAsync.getCardsDetails(correlationId, customer);

            logger.info("Awaiting threads request to be completed");
            CompletableFuture.allOf(loansDetails, cardsDetails).join();

            Accounts account = accountDetails.get();

            List<Loans> loansList = new ArrayList<>();
            List<Cards> cardsList = new ArrayList<>();

            try {
                loansList.addAll(loansDetails.get());
            } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException ex) {
                logger.warn(ex.toString());
                logger.warn("The call to GET loans details failed! Returning empty contactDetails body!");
            }

            try {
                cardsList.addAll(cardsDetails.get());
            } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException ex) {
                logger.warn(ex.toString());
                logger.warn("The call to GET cards details failed! Returning empty contactDetails body!");
            }

            ...
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.warn("Exception is --->>> {}", ex.toString());
            logger.warn("The call to GET account from database failed!");
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
        }

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(customerDetails);
    }
```

The Async methods:

```
@Async("taskExecutor")
public CompletableFuture<Accounts> getAccountsDetails(int customerId)
        throws InterruptedException {

    log.info("Attempting to retrieve accounts details, thread =  {}", Thread.currentThread().getName());
    Accounts accountDetails = accountsRepository.findByCustomerId(customerId);

    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(accountDetails);
}

@Async("taskExecutor")
public CompletableFuture<List<Loans>> getLoansDetails(
        String correlationId, Customer customer) throws InterruptedException {

    log.info("Attempting to retrieve loans details, thread =  {}", Thread.currentThread().getName());
    List<Loans> loansDetails =
            loansFeignClient.getLoansDetails(correlationId, customer);

    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(loansDetails);
}

@Async("taskExecutor")
public CompletableFuture<List<Cards>> getCardsDetails(
        String correlationId, Customer customer) throws Exception {

    log.info("Attempting to retrieve cards details, thread =  {}", Thread.currentThread().getName());
    List<Cards> cardDetails =
            cardsFeignClient.getCardDetails(correlationId, customer);

    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(cardDetails);
}
```

The configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class ConfigExecutor {

    @Bean(name = "taskExecutor")
    public Executor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(2);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(2);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(100);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("userThread-");
        executor.initialize();

        return executor;
    }
}
```

Using this code, the app works properly, I see in the logs that it creates 2 threads and uses the 2 threads for the 3 request. But if I delete the configuration class (so I don't configure the ThreadPoolTaskExecutor bean), the app compiles and runs perfectly, but I see in the logs that it uses only one thread:

```
2022-10-09 18:50:56.027  INFO [accounts,27e5f8bb1b00cda3,27e5f8bb1b00cda3] 2396 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.d.b.a.s.client.RetrieveDetailsAsync    : Attempting to retr
ieve accounts details, thread =  http-nio-8080-exec-1
Hibernate: select accounts0_.account_number as account_1_0_, accounts0_.account_type as account_2_0_, accounts0_.branch_address as branch_a3_0_, accounts0_.create_
dt as create_d4_0_, accounts0_.customer_id as customer5_0_ from accounts accounts0_ where accounts0_.customer_id=?
2022-10-09 18:50:56.341  INFO [accounts,27e5f8bb1b00cda3,27e5f8bb1b00cda3] 2396 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.d.b.a.s.client.RetrieveDetailsAsync    : Attempting to retr
ieve loans details, thread =  http-nio-8080-exec-1
2022-10-09 18:50:57.701  INFO [accounts,27e5f8bb1b00cda3,27e5f8bb1b00cda3] 2396 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.d.b.a.s.client.RetrieveDetailsAsync    : Attempting to retr
ieve cards details, thread =  http-nio-8080-exec-1
```

It look s that it creates and uses only one thread. So the 3 requests aren't done concurrently? From my research I understand that if I don't configure this ThreadPoolTaskExecutor bean, it will use SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor by default. If there is only one thread http-nio-8080-exec-1, does this mean that first request uses this thread, after the request is finished, the second request uses the same thread and after that the third request uses the same thread. So the request aren't done concurrently?

And another question is about ThreadPoolExecutor (the implementation for ExecutorService interface). What exactly is the difference between ThreadPoolTaskExecutor and ThreadPoolExecutor. Is the difference only the fact that the first is from spring framework and the second is from JEE? Because I see that both uses tasks concurrently? And because ThreadPoolTaskExecutor is from Spring framework, it is better to use it in Spring Boot projects. Thank you for response!

Comment: SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor fires up a new Thread for each task. So it is not used at all because you actually disabled @EnableAsync capability.

Answer (score 0):

When you delete the configuration class `ConfigExecutor`, you also disable asynchronous method execution capability feature enabled using the `@EnableAsync` annotation. Then your calls will be executed synchronously using the calling thread (in this case `http-nio-8080-exec-1`, which is handling your request).

If you don't create `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` bean, then the default `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` will be created using configuration class `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.task.TaskExecutionAutoConfiguration`.

The `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` uses internally `ThreadPoolExecutor`, therefore `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` can be seen as a wrapper for `ThreadPoolExecutor` enabling it to be configured in Spring application using configuration properties.